# Samsung M2026W, drivers installed, printer added but not working

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung, ubuntu-drivers

Good morning everyone. 
I recently re-installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer, but I'm having issues with the printer. It was working just fine before, but now seems like my computer doesn't like it anymore. 
I downloaded the drivers from the official HP page and run the install.sh file as i did before. Everything worked fine, drivers installed, but for some reason when i try to print something, it just won't work. 
I opened the "printers" panel and added the printer, it says it is "ready", but when i open libreoffice it comes back with the error:

> Could not start printer. Please check your printer configuration

I thought was a libreoffice issue, but even when exporting the document as a PDF it just doesn't work.

I'm not great with terminal etcetera, so if you need any information, please tell me what comand you want me to type and I'll paste the results!

thank you in advance!

Comment: you'b better go for a manual setup of your printer. From the Gnome control panel and feed it -if needed- with the description file (.ppd)  bundled in the constructor drivers package. See the applet named `system-config-printer`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I entered the gnome control panel, the printer is "ready" and everything looks absolutely fine. I have no ppd in the drivers package, only a folder named ppd with nothing inside. I was looking for it to install it via the printers panel but... couldn't find it. I even downloaded many time the file from the official page [https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2026-laser-printer-series/16462610] but nada...